# Making of a binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am given a Linked List Representation of complete binary tree in a format like so:

[image: diagram]

I have to convert linked list to complete binary tree.I am using a queue to do the same.I am storing the root in the queue storing it in a variable pointing this to a new node which I am making and then storing the left and right pointers and doing this again but I am getting only one node as output when preorder traversal is done on the self made tree.For eg. Linked list is 1->2->3->4->5->NULL but on preorder traversal I am getting 1 as output.

```
void convert(node *head,TreeNode * &root)
 {
     if(head==NULL){
        root=NULL;
        return;
    }
    queue<struct TreeNode* >Q;
    Q.push(root);     // Pushing root which is Null at start.
    while(head!=NULL){
        struct TreeNode * x=Q.front();     // storing
        Q.pop();                   //Popping
        x=new TreeNode;           //pointing this null pointer to a new node 
        x->data=head->data;      // storing data
        x->left=NULL;           //Making left of this point to NuLL
        x->right=NULL;         //Making right of this point to NuLL
        if(!root)root=x;      // If root is null point it to x.
        Q.push(x->left);      // Push the left child pointer which is NULL
        Q.push(x->right);     // Push the right child pointer which is NULL
        head=head->next;    // Move further in linked list.
     }
  }
```

Comment: Hints: what are the values `x->left` and `x->right`, which you push into the queue? What does `x=new TreeNode` do to the pointer you just got from the queue? When do you set the left and right pointers of a node to anything except `NULL`? (Bring out a pen(cil) and a bunch of paper and walk through your algorithm by hand.)

Comment: The binary tree on your picture isn't actually binary tree. Binary tree sorts elements by some criteria: usually less than parent element goes to left and to right overwise. Thants to this criteria searching in binary tree can be performed for `log(n)`. Thing that you are trying to make looks more like heap than tree.

Comment: @SemyonBurov Its a binary tree not bst

Comment: @molbdnilo Ok let me answer your questions, 
1) x->left,x->right are pointers node which is pointing NULL at the time of insertion.
2) x=new node points the new treenode to x.
3) Last one I am not really getting what you are saying.

Please let me know where am I wrong.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I tried debugging the code.I tried outputting the data stored in "x" before popping from queue which only gave me series of "0"es.I asked question after spending enough time on debugging and it is not really helping me out.I assure you that I have tried alot paper work also

Comment: @StackOverflow Spend more time in debugging, and watch how variable -values are changing (or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't post a complete answer, but I'll provide some debugging help.

Here are the first tree iterations of your loop, along with comments about how the variables change.
(It's a very good idea to write things like this down on paper as you trace through the program in your mind. It's less transient than a debugger view, and being able to move back in time while debugging is valuable.)

```
queue<struct TreeNode* >Q;          // Q: []
Q.push(root);                       // Q: [NULL]
while(head!=NULL){
    struct TreeNode * x=Q.front();  // x = NULL, Q: [NULL]
    Q.pop();                        // Q: []
    x=new TreeNode;                 // x: -> TreeNode {}
    x->data=head->data;             // 
    x->left=NULL;                   // 
    x->right=NULL;                  // x: ->TreeNode {data: data of initial head, 
                                    //                left: NULL, right:NULL}
    if(!root)root=x;                // root: ->TreeNode {data: data of initial head, 
                                    //                   left: NULL, right:NULL}
    Q.push(x->left);                // Q: [NULL]
    Q.push(x->right);               // Q: [NULL, NULL]
    head=head->next;                // Move further in linked list.
}
{
    struct TreeNode * x=Q.front();  // x = NULL, Q: [NULL, NULL]
    Q.pop();                        // Q: [NULL]
    x=new TreeNode;                 // x: -> TreeNode {}
    x->data=head->data;             // 
    x->left=NULL;                   // 
    x->right=NULL;                  // x: ->TreeNode {data: head->data, left: NULL, right:NULL}
    if(!root)root=x;                // root: still ->TreeNode {data: data of initial head, 
                                    //                         left: NULL, right:NULL}
    Q.push(x->left);                // Q: [NULL, NULL]
    Q.push(x->right);               // Q: [NULL, NULL, NULL]
    head=head->next;                // Move further in linked list.
}
{
    struct TreeNode * x=Q.front();  // x = NULL, Q: [NULL, NULL, NULL]
    Q.pop();                        // Q: [NULL, NULL]
    x=new TreeNode;                 // x: -> TreeNode {}
    x->data=head->data;             // 
    x->left=NULL;                   // 
    x->right=NULL;                  // x: ->TreeNode {data: head->data, left: NULL, right:NULL}
    if(!root)root=x;                // root: still ->TreeNode {data: data of initial head, 
                                    //                         left: NULL, right:NULL}
    Q.push(x->left);                // Q: [NULL, NULL, NULL]
    Q.push(x->right);               // Q: [NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL]
    head=head->next;                // Move further in linked list.
}
```

As you can see, you're pushing and popping a series of null pointers into the queue.
You never use the values from the queue for anything.

To clarify the problem, suppose you had a queue of integers and did this:

```
struct S { int x; };
S s;
s.x = 0;
queue<int> q;
q.push(s.x);
int y = q.front();
y = 96;
```

I'm pretty sure you wouldn't expect the value of `s.x` to suddenly become `96` instead of `0`.
Pointers work in exactly the same way.

You also never modify the root node you created, which is why you only get a one-node tree (the other nodes are just memory leaks).

You could

- Pop a tree node pointer
- Get the next *two* elements from the list (if they exist)
- Make new nodes from the list elements as appropriate
- Set the left and right pointers of the popped node to these two new ones
- Push the new pointers into the queue
- Repeat

Comment: Thank you.One last doubt.I am doing nothing but making single node many time and assigning that the value of current head than I move forward and make another single node and so on.But sir when I push x->left,x->right in the queue why isn't its value getting modified when I am assigning it to a new node in next iteration ? When I am popping it from the queue isn't it the same left pointer to the node ?

Comment: Oh maybe now I got it...since I am copying the Q.front() to x so we actually pointing another pointer to node left child i,e our current Q.front() so when we do x=new TreeNode than the pointer which we made to point on Q.front() starts pointing to this new allocated memory and our x->left and x->right remain as such.Please confirm it sir.Am I right or wrong ?

Comment: @StackOverflow Added a bit to try and clarify the problem.